# I want a nav and banner picture to fit next to a logo in a header tag, how might I do that?

Tags: html, css

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seNzp/1) that is a rough draft of what I'm trying to do.

I'd like to have a logo image the full `height` of a banner on the left, and a `nav` on top of an image spanning the rest of the `width` of the `header` on the *right*.

In the jsfiddle there is no spanning image, but I'd like it there eventually.

Any insight would be fantastic!

```
<div class="site">
    <header id="header">
        <img class="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/American-Eskimo-dog.jpg" />
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PAGE4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>

header .logo {
    padding: 25px;
    width: 142px;
    height: 200;
    background-color: rgba(0, 169, 199, 1.0);
    border: 4px solid rgba(150, 13, 117, 1.0);
    display: inline;
}
header nav {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-bottom: 5px rgba(150, 13, 117, 1.0) solid;
    height: 200px;
}
header nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0 6px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Bebas-Neue;
    list-style-type: none;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: top .3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
header nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0, 169, 199, 1.0);
    text-shadow: -.3px .1px rgb(25, 128, 175);
}
.site {
    width: 1000px;
}
}
```

Comment: Hey guys, I can understand your frustration, but the chunk of code is tiny and it's much more difficult to read on stackoverflow than in the fiddle. That is, this question cannot be answered without a visualization.

Comment: @SamJacobs The point of code in the question is so that the question can be used as a reference to future users looking for help on a similar question.  If JSFiddle were to be brought down or lost that fiddle, this question would be of no use to anyone.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/seNzp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

**Fiddle**: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seNzp/2/)</kbd>

Just change the image `width` to `100%`:

```
.bannerImage {
    width: 100%
}
```

And add a `navbox` surrounding the full navigation block:

```
#navbox {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 204px);
}
```